# Dependency Injection in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I would like to initialize my `MessageSource` field with Dependency Injection in Spring. This is what have so far:

```
package com.ucmas.cms.view;

@Component
public class PdfRevenueReportView extends AbstractPdfView {
  ...
  @Autowired
  private MessageSource messageSource;
  ...
}
```

`mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="sec://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ucmas.cms.controller,com.ucmas.cms.view" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    ...
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
       <beans:property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/spring-pdf-views.xml" />
       <beans:property name="order" value="0" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

I have defined my messageSource in `root-context.xml`

```
<bean id="messageSource"    

class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
```

My controller classes work fine, however I am unable to inject the messageSource field in the `PdfRevenueReportView` class. What should I do to make the DI works ?

**UPDATED**

I define the view in xml as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">
    <bean id="PdfRevenueSummary" class="com.ucmas.cms.view.PdfRevenueReportView" />
</beans>
```

Perhaps this is why the messageSource is always null ?

Comment: have you defined a messageSource bean somewhere ?

Comment: yes in my `root-context.xml`

Comment: According to this config there should be a file named 'messages' with no extensions on your classpath. Is there such a file ?

Comment: There's such file with extension because I am using `i18n`. The messageSource is injected successfully in my controllers but not in that view class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by updating my spring-pdf-views.xml into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">
    <bean id="PdfRevenueSummary" class="com.ucmas.cms.view.PdfRevenueReportView">
        <property name="messageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

However this requires me to generate setter and getter for messageSource field and removing the `@Autowired` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

In your `dispatcher servlets` configuration you need to create a bean for the message source.

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="directory/with/messagesource"/>
</bean>
```

Also ensure that the `messages` directory is on the classpath.

Comment: I have defined that, in fact the message source can be retrieve in my controller classes.

Comment: @abiieez I'm not sure if this matters but I have defined my message source in the config file for the dispatcher servlet instead of the applications context.  I think there may be issues that the controllers cannot see the beans in the application config.

Answer (score 0):

You are annotating messageSource with Autowired. This might not work when your bean *messageSource* whilst is an interface of MessageResource, is really the implementation *ResourceBundleMessageSource*.

I think your DI would have worked if you used @Resource instead as it is name based:

```
@Resource
private MessageSource messageSource;
```